# how to get commit text inside intellij plugin classes

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

IntelliJ CE 2018.3.1 plugin 
I have the plugin like https://github.com/MobileTribe/commit-template-idea-plugin
I want to realize scenario: user put smth in commit field, then click my button. His text must be in fields on my form. 
How I can get this text inside DialogWrapper or AnAction?

Answer (score 0):

I found. If anyone will be looking for a similar problem:

```
    Object obj =  VcsDataKeys.COMMIT_MESSAGE_CONTROL.getData(actionEvent.getDataContext());
    String cntrl = "null";
    if (obj instanceof com.intellij.openapi.vcs.ui.CommitMessage) {
        cntrl = ((com.intellij.openapi.vcs.ui.CommitMessage)obj).getComment();
    }
```